# ROS publisher speed

Tags: publish-subscribe, ros

I am running a ros publisher/subscriber node, which receives a single image from a /image_pub topic , do some processing and publish the results on /results topic. The image_pub topic is publishing at 20Hz but my publisher/subscriber node runs at 12 hz(i found it using rostopic hz /results). Is there any way to improve the speed or tell my program to run at 20Hz. At start it was running at 20Hz. Then i turned off my Linux for lunch, came back and restarted my program. Now its running at 12 hz. I have restarted it again and again but still runs at 12 hz. Any solution..?

Answer (score 0):

If your image processing takes longer than 1/20 second than there is no way you can achieve the 20Hz. If that is not the case then the following main loop will do the job

```
ros::Rate publish_rate(20);
while(ros::ok())
{
  // do some processing
  publisher.publish(image);
  publish_rate.sleep();
}
```

The `ros::Rate` will make sure to sleep for the right amount of time to achieve the 20Hz.
Also make sure to compile in `Release` mode (`catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`) as this will speed up you code  by a good margin.

Comment: Yes you are right, the problem was in my subscriber call back, i am using ORB features, and some times it detects a large  number of feature points, making processing difficult. So now i have limited the number of features and its working better. Thanks for the help :)